# How do I assign multiple values taken from user to a single key stored in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to create a number of lists that store a number of values.  Each list is mentioned as class in my code.  I want to add values for each key, one by one, in the dictionary that is taken from a user.

This is my code so far:

```
n = input('Enter the number of classe: ')
class_count = int(n)
listDict = {}

for i in range(1, class_count):
    listDict["class_" + str(i)] = []
    print(listDict)
```

**Output:**

```
Enter the number of classe: 4
{'class_1': []}
{'class_1': [], 'class_2': []}
{'class_1': [], 'class_2': [], 'class_3': []}
```

Comment: What is the problem here?

Comment: What's the question? You've assigned them.

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate to `class_count+1` since even though you start a 1, it doesn't mean the `range` function will iterate one additional time, it'll actually simply iterate one less time.

Also you should probably use an `OrderedDict` in order to retain order of the classes:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
listDict = OrderedDict()
class_count = 4
for i in range(1,class_count+1):
     listDict["class_"+str(i)] = []

print listDict
>>>OrderedDict([('class_1', []), ('class_2', []), ('class_3', []), ('class_4', [])])
```

Comment: nice one, +1 for ordered dict

Comment: sorry i think you got my question wrong. i want to add values in these lists({'class_1': [], 'class_2': []) that get generated. how do i do that?

Comment: If it's inside the loop simply put the values straight into the `[]` list ( `listDict["class_"+str(i)] = [1,2,3]`) if it's outside the loop you can access it like this: `listDict['class_1'][0] = 1` which would place 1 in the first index of the first list

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at python's `defaultdict` construct:

```
from collections import defaultdict
listDict = defaultdict(list)
```

And then, just write

```
listDict['class_{i}'.format(i=0)].append(value)
```

No need to initialize `listDict['class_{i}'.format(i=0)]` to be `[]`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a userid for each user, use that as the key and then assign each class value to a list for that user such as the following:

```
def generateuserid():
    """
    generate user id for each user input
    :return: userid
    """
    for i in range(100):
        yield 'user{}'.format(i)

# initiate generator
users = generateuserid()

n=input('Enter the number of classe: ')
listDict = {}

# for each user, retrieve next id
user = next(users)

for i in range(1,int(n)):
    if user in listDict.keys():
        listDict[user].append('class_{}'.format(i))
    else:
        listDict[user] = ['class_{}'.format(i)]
    print(listDict) #{'user1': ['class_1', 'class_2', 'class_3', 'class_4', 'class_5', 'class_6', 'class_7', 'class_8', 'class_9']}
```